# Animate Loading in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, loading, dispatcher

I have button on my window. After user **clickes** the button i want my **application to animate loading label (with rotationg it), during the other thread gets some data from database**. **After loading data from DB animation must end**. The task seems simple , but it doesn't work.
The problem is that animation whatever i do animation starts only after loading from the database when it is not needed.

*Help please. Here some code:*

```
private void LoginButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
  Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
    delegate()
    {
      DispatcherOperation dispatcherOp =
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(
          delegate()
          {
            var da = new DoubleAnimation(360, 0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
            var rt = new RotateTransform();
            loadingLabel.RenderTransform = rt;
            loadingLabel.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
            da.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
            rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da);
          }));
      dispatcherOp.Completed += new EventHandler(DispatcherOpCompleted);
    }));
  thread.Start();
}

void DispatcherOpCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Loading From Database
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dispatcher.Completed event is executed on the main UI thread. Your worker thread is just queueing the dispatcher operation and exiting. Instead of creating a thread that starts the animation and then doing your database loading in the Completed handler, just start your animation in the main thread, and then create a worker thread to do the database loading.

```
private void LoginButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var da = new DoubleAnimation(360, 0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
  var rt = new RotateTransform();
  loadingLabel.RenderTransform = rt;
  loadingLabel.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
  da.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
  rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da);

  Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoadData));
  thread.Start();
}

void LoadData()
{
  //Loading From Database

  // Use a Dispatch.BeginInvoke here to stop the animation
  // and do any other UI updates that use the results of the database load
}
```